# perspective of 3D mesh Matrix

Tags: matrices

Please See:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/c4z2wpabny
I'm trying to add the perspective, and i have tried using  a perspective matrix but apparently matrix multiplication with a perspective projection matrix still requires each component to be divided by W(δ), even so if this is not the case i still cannot achieve perspective without polarity flips, my best guess is that the Euler method is either not implemented correctly or is insufficient and requires the use of quaternion.
feel free to send me a link to an altered version of the project if you wish.

Comment: please help anyone

Comment: Please explain what it is that you’re trying to accomplish and what your question actually is. We’re not mind-readers here, and poking around at a random Desmos project isn’t particularly illuminating, nor will many people even follow the link.

Comment: @amd the reason i posted the link is to show what im currently attempting to achieve perspective. all i want is to create the perspective effect on the cube like shape, and so fare It works until i combined two rotations, x pi/2 then y rotation breaks the perspective effect. im fairly new to the idea and so far trying to add the frustum through a standard perspective matrix didn't work(i don't know if i did not apply it correctly) all i want is simply to project the mesh so that vertices with smaller z depth are closer to the origin.